# What's the difference between this WHERE clause and this Join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

What's the difference between this:

`SELECT *
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.primary_id = table2.primary_id`

And this:

`SELECT *
FROM table1
FULL JOIN table2 ON table1.primary_id = table2.primary_id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first query is an implicit `INNER JOIN`, you should always use the explicit syntax. In that case, the query will return the records that are in table1 and in table2. The second query will return all the records of both tables, showing `NULL` if there are no match on the other.

Comment: +1 For sliding in just ahead of me with almost exactly the same thing I was typing.

Comment: Right Right, I must be really tired you're right the FULL JOIN will give me those extra null results, however you said it's an implicit INNER JOIN, so had I used INNER JOIN on the 2nd query in my example it would be the same but not recommended?

Comment: It should be the same and **recommended** to use `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @user519753 That's what JOINs are for. So use them, they're much easier to read than where statements (when there are more than 2 tables joined)

Comment: You should **always** use explicit joins, in your second query it would be an `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

The `FULL JOIN` keyword returns all the rows from the `table1`, and all the rows from `table2`. If there are rows in `table1` that do not have matches in `table2`, or if there are rows in `table2` that do not have matches in `table1`, those rows will be listed as well, filled with `nulls`.

The first query will only return results where `table1` has a match on `table2` (`primaryId`). It is the equivalent of an `INNER JOIN`.